# Java exception handling

Tags: java, parsing, exception, date-parsing

Hi I am trying to use the following piece of code i got a parse exception and need to know how to handle

```
DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date1 = (Date)formatter1.parse(startDate);
Date date2 = (Date)formatter1.parse(endDate);               
DateFormat formatter2=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String startDate1=formatter2.format(date1);
String endDate1=formatter2.format(date2);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: would be nice to see your input and exception message

Comment: you got a parse exception, can we have one too?

Comment: Whats in "startdate" and "enddate"??

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html

Comment: can you please put your exception msg as well

Comment: We don't have nearly enough context to know how you should handle the exception. Is this user input? If so, you should be showing the user an error message. Is it system input from a file, for example? If so, perhaps you should ignore that record, or perhaps you should abort the operation completely. There's no one-size-fits-all approach to exception handling.

Comment: I think title could be wrong. You wan to know how to handle an exception or how to fix the error? They are different things.

Comment: How you handle the exception really is up to you.  What do you think should happen when the user passes you bad data?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [getErrorOffset()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html#getErrorOffset%28%29):

```
DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
try
{
   Date date1 = (Date)formatter1.parse(startDate);
   Date date2 = (Date)formatter1.parse(endDate);              
}catch(ParseException e)
{
  // Handle Exception, take a look at e.ErrorOffset to know where the problem occurs
  // if the Message doesnt give enough information
}            
DateFormat formatter2=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");            
String startDate1=formatter2.format(date1);             
String endDate1=formatter2.format(date2);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put put your exception msg,

```
    Date date1 = null, date2= null;
    DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


    try {
        date1 = (Date)formatter1.parse("08/01/1988");
        date2 = (Date)formatter1.parse("08/01/2000");
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        //Handle Exception here
    }
    DateFormat formatter2=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String startDate1=formatter2.format(date1);
    String endDate1=formatter2.format(date2);

    System.out.println(startDate1);
    System.out.println(endDate1);
```